# First time using Ubuntu not sure the installation is correct

Tags: installation, boot, dual-boot, mount, xubuntu

So I got fed up with Microsoft and decided I was going to start using exclusively open source products. Very little experience outside the Windows OS environment so I picked Ubuntu which I thought would be a good starting point. I created the ISO disk and deleted windows. I began running Ubuntu and encountered some things during installation which I was unsure about. First off I got a message stating I hadn't created /boot. So I went back and fumbled my way through that. Then I got a message saying I hadn't created /swap. I went back to try and do that, but I got an entirely new prompt and when I clicked it it completed the installation.

All was fine but then I tried to install Solaris. When my machine restarted I got an error saying that there was no bootable media and that I needed to enter a bootable disk etc...

I removed the Solaris disk and tried several times to restart. Each time getting the same message about no bootable media. I tried using the Ubuntu ISO and KD bootdisk and still got the same error message. There was no command prompt and no way to format. I went into BIOS and changed the boot order and it still would not boot from CD. This morning I opened my computer and when I brought it out of hibernation it went straight to the Ubuntu desktop.

I am guessing that I did not properly configure something during the install but I do not understand why, when even with a bootdisk entered it would not boot from the disk. Now when I try and access my HDD from Ubuntu desktop I get the error message Unable to mount location. Can't mount file.

I see when I open the file system folder there is a boot folder. So long story short is there some way to check my installation or to get detailed install instructions and I will just reinstall.

Comment: You are making a problem more complex than what it is. You should say: *I have this OSs intalled, and now I want to remove this and install this* not make a **huge** story. Please, take a time and edit your question and make it more simple and short than what it is now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. I'd advise you to read about MBR/GPT(bios and uefi too), bootloaders(grub,etc.),
2. I don't think your problem has anything to do with Ubuntu
3. The installation of Ubuntu is straightforward, you either choose manual partitioning or you let it format your drive. Basically you need a root partition and one for swap. You can create additional for /home,/tmp,etc. if you want.
4. When installing Ubuntu it will show you your HDD as for example /dev/sda, and you can select to which disk to record the bootloader(the software which lets your computer start the OS)
5. Basically in a MBR booting scheme, you have partitions which are made bootable, and a bootloader - probably Grub, which lets you select what to boot.
6. So to sum it all up: You choose the bootable media from bios: cd(dvd)/usb/hdd,etc.
7. After that the system boots from it, if there's no bootloader it will tell some error along the lines of that. Also most modern PC's have a boot priority lists, so if no boot sector is found in the first media, it will try the second,etc.
8. If you choose to boot from media other than your hdd, and it won't boot, then something is wrong with the media or your bios. You can try using another dvd/usb flash and/or flashing the bios. Also you can try unplugging your HDD prior to booting from the media. And of course try booting from it on another pc, so you're sure it's bootable. Also double check your settings to be sure it's trying to boot from the right source.
9. By bootable I mean there's this thing called boot sector which allows the computer to start it. It's not a file, and thus not shown as such in file managers.
   Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I will take your advice and read on those topics.